# Power BI- Password Protect a tab

Tags: powerbi

I have a dashboard where I have details of different leaders (one page for each leader). I want a formula which will enable to password protect the tab and only the person who has the password can input it and open that tab. Like we have in excel where a macro code is written to open a worksheet only by a password

I am expecting a summary page where i can create a slicer for all the leaders and when the leader clicks on his filter he should be prompted for a password and once password is provided it should take the leader to his individual page which will have only his details

Comment: Cool. What have you tried so far and what happened? See [ask].

Answer (score 1):

You can use row-level security ("RLS") to restrict what each individual would see.  This way, you wouldn't need multiple pages, or a summary page.

Comment: Just to add, there isn't a "password" like feature in Power BI, nor is there a way to restrict pages in a report. RLS is the answer. [Row-level security (RLS) with Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/enterprise/service-admin-rls)